# Remove special character from AsyncStorage getitem data

Tags: javascript, asyncstorage

I'm getting AsyncStorage data but there i'm getting special character `\` which was not there when i set the item. Don't know why this is being added. Anyway i'm trying to remove this character from my data. I have tried the following way to do that:

```js
data = ["{\"word\":\"Cat\",\"pronunciation\":null,\"definitions\":[{\"type\":\"noun\",\"definition\":\"a small domesticated carnivorous mammal with soft fur, a short snout, and retractile claws. It is widely kept as a pet or for catching mice, and many breeds have been developed.\",\"example\":\"their pet cat\",\"image_url\":\"https://media.owlbot.info/dictionary/images/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac.jpg.400x400_q85_box-42,0,943,900_crop_detail.jpg\",\"emoji\":\"\"}]}",

var b=JSON.stringify(data);
var str = b.replace(/\\/g, '');
var final = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(final);
```

Now this throws error `Unexpected token { in JSON at position 3` . How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want to call `JSON.parse` with the elements within `data`, rather than `data` itself. The `data` variable is an array, but the elements within it are JSON. For example:

```js
const data = [...];
const parsedData = data.map(datum => JSON.parse(datum));
```

Comment: can you please show me how to replace the backslashes while maping your way? @LukeBailey

Comment: I don't think you need to, that's what `JSON.parse` does. It converts JSON into objects. Try it out and let me know if it works. Or do you want to just have a string that doesn't have those backslashes?

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP code has a typo. AsyncStorage would return a string which is escaped - not an array. Either way, that is valid stringified JSON and JSON.parse will remove the escape characters